# Wrong path to bower components after using grunt-wiredep

Tags: drupal, gruntjs, bower, grunt-wiredep

I'm trying to get Bower to work within my Drupal projects. In the root of my project I have a `bower.json` and `.bowerrc` file. 
Bower components are being installed in `sites/all/themes/mytheme/libraries`.

I've setup grunt-wiredep to automatically inject my bower components in my `html.tpl.php`file, like this:

```
wiredep: {
    task: {
        src: 'sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/html.tpl.php'          
    }
}
```

When using `grunt wiredep`, the plugin injects the following path to my `index.tpl.php` file:

```
<script src="../libraries/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

Where it should be this:

```
<script src="sites/all/themes/mytheme/libraries/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

I've tried adding `directory: 'sites/all/thems/mytheme';` to the wiredep task, but then I get the error that my dependencies are not installed.

Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I got it working now. Here's what I did:

1) I ignored the first part of the path: `../`

2) For html files, I replaced the references to the js and css dependencies. I added `sites/all/themes/mytheme/` to the path.

Here is what my wiredep task now looks like:

```
wiredep: {
    task: {
        src: 'sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/html.tpl.php',
        ignorePath: '../',
        fileTypes: {
            html: {
                replace: {
                    js: '<script src="sites/all/themes/mytheme/{{filePath}}"></script>',
                    css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="sites/all/themes/mytheme/{{filePath}}"/>',
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```